# Cómo corregir este bloque Python, que no ejecuta correctamente?

Tags: python-3.x

Hola amigos soy nuevo en python me dejaron este ejercicio he tratado de resolverlo pero nada que le busco solución si alguien pudiese ayudarme o a encontrar el error que estoy cometiendo se lo agradecería

EJERCICIO:
Resuelva el siguiente ejercicio en el Lenguaje Python:
Se desea comprar un vehículo financiado: La forma de pago es una cuota inicial del 20% y el 80% restante en 40 cuotas mensuales; a cada cuota mensual se le carga el 2% sobre el saldo de la deuda. Escriba un programa que reciba como entrada el costo del vehículo, y devuelva el valor de la cuota inicial y de cada una de las cuotas mensuales:

Codigo

```
def mostrar_cuotas(valor):
  cuotaIni = (valor * 0.2)
  cuotaSec = (valor - cuotaIni)
  cuotaMen = (cuotaSec / 40)
  totalPag = 0
  print("El vehiculo tiene costo de: ",valorVehi)
  print("--------------------------------------")

  print("La cuota inicial del vehiculo es: ",cuotaIni)
  print("--------------------------------------------")

  for i in range(40):
     vIrCuotaAct = cuotaMen + ((cuotaSec - cuotaMen) * 0.02)
     cuotaSec -= cuotaMen
     print("El valor de cuota N" +str(i+1)+"es:\n" )
     print("$ " + str(int(vIrCuotaAct)))
     print("**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**")
     totalPag += vIrCuotaAct
  valorVehi = float(input("ingrese el valor del vehiculo que desea financiar:"))
  mostrar_cuotas(valor)
```

Comment: El código debe ir como texto por favor, y tienes un error de indentación recuerda que phyton es muy sensible a las tabulaciones. ;)

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. "Actividad Python Colaboración" no es un título válido, debes colocar en el título el problema en cuestión. 2. El código va _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. 3. Como te han dicho: Python es MUY sensible a las tabulaciones :) Lee [ask].

Comment: Como dijo nuestro compañero Israel, [es importante que pongas el código como texto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%C3%B3digo-vale-m%C3%A1s-que-mil-im%C3%A1genes-c%C3%B3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu). Y como dijo también, tu error está en que te falta indentar el código. Las indentaciones le dicen a Python "este pedazo de codigo pertenece a esta funcion" o "este pedazo de código pertenece al bucle for" o "este codigo pertenece a x cosa"

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lHOPqubgVndE26e633MMBgBbZBoLMCAV?usp=sharing


aqui dejo el codigo la verdad me perdi un poquito

Comment: Dos cosas. Primero, entendiste la causa que los tres te dijimos? La indentanción son los espacios que van a la izquierda del código. Si ves ejemplos de Python seguramente lo veas. Y segundo, el código va copiado y pegado en la pregunta, con formato. Puedes darle formato seleccionando todo el código y presionando las {} arriba de la caja de texto.

Comment: Recuerda que los links se pueden caer y así la pregunta quedaría inservible para aquellos que la vean en el futuro.

Comment: como se coloca para poner mensaje el codigo :(

Comment: Como es Python, te será sencillo colocar el texto entre triples acentos graves (```). Al editar la pregunta, también verás la ayuda (con el ícono del signo de interrogación, a la derecha).

Comment: Bien hecho! :D ahora solo queda entender bien nuestros comentarios y sabrás cual es la causa del error! Edit: me di cuenta que ahora no se ve el error... Podrías arreglarlo por favor?

Comment: Hice mi mejor esfuerzo para explicartelo con una imagen. Si aun asi no lo entiendes, no sabre como ayudarte, perdon... Aqui tienes el link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7mES.png

Comment: amigo ahi ya esta el codigo please helpme y me sale siempre este error



( File "<ipython-input-13-2fa049e14ddf>", line 3
    cuotaIni = (valor * 0.2)
           ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Ya se, pero no quiero resolver tu error nada más, quiero que aprendas del error para que algún dia puedas resolverlo por ti mismo. Es por ti que trato de que aprendas.

Comment: Además, no estoy seguro de dar una respuesta, pues la comunidad podría recibir mal mi respuesta (tendrán sus razones para ello).

Comment: entiendo que aprenda acerca de los espacios vi como se le hace pero aun asi me da error no se si todavia error y es el mismo :(

Comment: Aplicaste la indentación a tu código? O le hiciste alguna modificación? Si es así actualiza tu pregunta por favor. Aunque yo creo que no indentaste bien el código.

Comment: ya lo actualice amigo como que si lo hice mal :(

Comment: Tu código me da este error: `unmatched ')'`. A vos te da ese mismo error?

Comment: no amigo me da uno diferente porque utilizo google cobaboratory

Comment: Tranquilo, nadie nace sabiendo c: Yo un dia estube trabado como 4 dias con un error y era por que me faltaba poner un parentesis xD

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: ESTE AMIGO



File "<ipython-input-19-061756cfe8e6>", line 13
    vIrCuotaAct = cuotaMen + ((cuotaSec - cuotaMen) * 0.02))
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax




tiene razon yo llevo una semana y todavia no encuentro el error solo quiero aprender XD le pregunte a mi profe y solo me dijo lea el pdf :(

Comment: Que raro que a mi no me salga ese error. Probá con quitar el ultimo paréntesis de la linea 13. Quizá se soluciona. Por que a mi me da ese error por que hay un parentesis de mas.

Comment: amigo y si lo pasas a google cobaboratory no se demora nada es solo una extension en drive y ya helpme please

Comment: Mejor te paso la linea 13 por aca `vIrCuotaAct = cuotaMen + ((cuotaSec - cuotaMen) * 0.02)`

Comment: Tranquilo, yo tampoco se bien la causa del error. Estamos viendo que pasa entre los dos.

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax    me sale esto

Comment: Te sigue saliendo ese error a pesar del cambio que te dije que hagas?

Comment: ya pero no me sale nada jajajajaj XD osea ya no me sale error pero diablos no me sale para meter el valor como lo tenia pensado .(

Comment: Espera, entonces ya no aparece ningún error, pero tu programa no hace nada?

Comment: exacto amigo no hace nada :(

Comment: Yo creo que ya casi está solucionado :D la ultima linea (que llama a la funcion que creaste) la pusiste dentro de la funcion. Sabes como sacarla para afuera de la función??? El problema se debe a que la funcion se crea, pero no es llamada en ningun lado.

Comment: No pero te hago el ejemplo a ver si estoy en lo correcto

mostrar_cuotas(valor) ----Antes
mostrar_cuotas()----- Despues

si es asi o estoy cometiendo error otra vez amigo

Comment: No entiendo tu ejemplo. Pero la forma es sacar dos espacios a la izquierda, que mostrar_cuotas(valor) quede a la misma altura que el def.

Comment: Como asi amigo no te entiendo lo que entendi es mover a la izquierda la ultima linea de codigo:  mostrar_cuotas(valor) y que quede a la misma altura de la primer linea de codigo: def mostrar_cuotas(valor):

Comment: `mostrar_cuotas(valor)` está dentro del bloque `def mostrar_cuotas` porque está tabulado de esa forma. Seguro que es lo que quieres?

Comment: y como lo saco dentro del bloque

Comment: ya me funciona muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Es un problema de indentación. Las dos últimas líneas deben estar pegadas a la izquierda:

```
def mostrar_cuotas(valor):
    cuotaIni = (valor * 0.2)
    cuotaSec = (valor - cuotaIni)
    cuotaMen = (cuotaSec / 40)
    totalPag = 0
    print("El vehiculo tiene costo de: ", valor)
    print("--------------------------------------")

    print("La cuota inicial del vehiculo es: ", cuotaIni)
    print("--------------------------------------------")

    for i in range(40):
        vIrCuotaAct = cuotaMen + ((cuotaSec - cuotaMen) * 0.02)
        cuotaSec -= cuotaMen
        print("El valor de cuota N" + str(i + 1) + "es:\n")
        print("$ " + str(int(vIrCuotaAct)))
        print("**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**")
        totalPag += vIrCuotaAct

valor = float(input("ingrese el valor del vehiculo que desea financiar:"))
mostrar_cuotas(valor)
```

Fijate que también elimine la variable `valorVehi`.

Eso produce algo así:

```
ingrese el valor del vehiculo que desea financiar:1000
El vehiculo tiene costo de:  1000.0
--------------------------------------
La cuota inicial del vehiculo es:  200.0
--------------------------------------------
El valor de cuota N1es:

$ 35
**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**
El valor de cuota N2es:

$ 35
**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**
El valor de cuota N3es:

$ 34
```